# get the DST boundaries of a given timezone in python

Tags: python, pytz

Is it possible to get the DST boundaries of a given timezone with pytz?

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't seem to be officially supported. However, you can poke at the internals of a `DstTzInfo` object and get it from there:

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> tz = timezone('Europe/London')
>>> tz._utc_transition_times
[datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1916, 5, 21, 2, 0),
...
datetime.datetime(2036, 3, 30, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2036, 10, 26, 1, 0),
datetime.datetime(2037, 3, 29, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2037, 10, 25, 1, 0)]
```

Each entry corresponds to an entry in `_transition_info`:

```
>>> tz._transition_info
[(datetime.timedelta(0), datetime.timedelta(0), 'GMT'),
(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'BST'),
...
(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'BST'),
(datetime.timedelta(0), datetime.timedelta(0), 'GMT'),
(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), 'BST'),
(datetime.timedelta(0), datetime.timedelta(0), 'GMT')]
```

And the source tells us what these mean:

```
_utc_transition_times = None # Sorted list of DST transition times in UTC
_transition_info = None # [(utcoffset, dstoffset, tzname)] corresponding
                        # to _utc_transition_times entries
```

Of course, this is implementation-dependent and you'd probably want to depend on particular versions of pytz that are known to work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that last sentence.  Pytz has revisions like anything else, but are/were there actually different implementations of it?

Comment: Who knows? You're accessing a field that starts with an underscore, which is not part of the documented API. The pytz authors may change it at any moment.

Comment: Is there an implementation in core Python by now?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Comment: python 3.9 has [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), which is roughly equivalent to pytz -- but afaict this trick doesn't work with it :)

Comment: The [tzdata](https://github.com/python/tzdata) package most probably has a up-to-date list of all the DST changes. Did not check how to parse the data files.