# Why does this code work on Linux but not on Windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x, pytz

I asked a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467759/flag-daylight-saving-time-dst-hours-in-pandas-date-time-column), regarding flagging Daylight Saving Time hours. @MattMessersmith kindly and expertly answered my question, and his solution **worked perfectly in Linux** (Ubuntu), **but not on either of my Windows machines** (work and home).

My Windows machines are both running Anaconda with Python 3.6 and pytz 2018.4, if that helps.

When I run the code on Windows, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<ipython-input-185-ed30519c4311>", line 1, in <module> 
  transition_times = [t.astimezone(tz) for t in transition_times] 
File "<ipython-input-185-ed30519c4311>", line 1, in <listcomp> 
  transition_times = [t.astimezone(tz) for t in transition_times] 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Here is the code that produces the error on my Windows machines:

```
from pytz import timezone

# Map transition times to year for some efficiency gain                                                                                                                                                     
tz = timezone('America/Denver')
transition_times = tz._utc_transition_times[1:]
transition_times = [t.astimezone(tz) for t in transition_times]
```

Comment: not sure if you saw that already: [how-can-i-convert-windows-timezones-to-timezones-pytz-understands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156597/how-can-i-convert-windows-timezones-to-timezones-pytz-understands) - there is one answer wich contains further links that might help you solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug: [[Windows] datetime.fromtimestamp(t) when 0 <= t <= 86399 fails on Python 3.6](https://bugs.python.org/issue29097).

Because some `datetime object` in `tz._utc_transition_times[1:]` is less than `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000`.