# looking for Pandas.DateTimeIndex.is_dst()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DateFrame with a DateTimeIndex, i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('2018-04-01', periods=96, freq='15T', tz='Australia/Sydney', name='timestamp')
df = dates.to_frame(index=False)
df.set_index(dates.name, inplace=True)
```

I want to create a column with an 0/1 indicator column which is 1 during summer time and 0 during winter, but I cannot find the relevant dst / is_dst attribute, i.e. I want something like

```
df['is_dst'] = df.index.is_dst()
```

can anyone advise that the correct method / property is. Or Do I need to covert to a different 'datetime' class?

I need something general - i.e. work for any timezone including say 'Australia/Brisbane' which doesn't have daylight savings. I'd prefer not to have to parse out the timezone offset and try and determine if it's summer / winter.

Comment: Maybe this can help your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124436/python-datetime-to-season

Comment: Thanks @SanchitKumar, that's useful although I prefer the accepted answer as it gives me the datetime information. The answer you link assumes summer / winter transition is start / end of month

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It have in [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.dst.html)

```
df.index.map(lambda x : x.dst())
```

After a small change can yield the Boolean

```
df.index.map(lambda x : int(x.dst().total_seconds()!=0))
Out[104]: 
Int64Index([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           dtype='int64', name='timestamp')
```

Comment: do I really have to use a `lambda` mapping here? shouldn't there be an easier option along the lines of `df['datetime'].dt.is_dst`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that Wen's method may be a bit faster, but heres a way of working with the underlying Python `datetime` objects with the [`isdst` attribute from `datetime.timetuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple):

```
>>> is_dst = [x.timetuple().tm_isdst for x in df.index.to_pydatetime()]
>>> pd.Series(is_dst).head()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
dtype: int64
>>> pd.Series(is_dst).tail()
91    0
92    0
93    0
94    0
95    0
dtype: int64
```

Example for a single value:

`.timetuple()` returns a `time.struct_time`;

> The tm_isdst flag of the result is set according to the dst() method: tzinfo is None or dst() returns None, tm_isdst is set to -1; else if dst() returns a non-zero value, tm_isdst is set to 1; else tm_isdst is set to 0.

```
>>> df.index[0].to_pydatetime().timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=91, tm_isdst=1)
```

The constructor will simply [check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/88cbea4c6ff4987ce31f4fe6f73c2d04a3d37829/Lib/datetime.py#L1661) if the date's `.dst()` attribute is None, nonzero, or some nonzero value:

```
    def timetuple(self):
        "Return local time tuple compatible with time.localtime()."
        dst = self.dst()
        if dst is None:
            dst = -1
        elif dst:
            dst = 1
        else:
            dst = 0
```

Comment: It has the method in pandas :-)